# Upgrade issue with XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, pulseaudio

I am trying to upgrade my machine (results below) but I am running into an issue with an audio package: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR.

I saw a "fix" for installing Ubuntu on windows machines, but it does not work on my current Ubuntu machine.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

```
johndoe@system76-pc:~$ RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                
Fetched 1,267 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                               
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable InRelease      
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease         
Hit https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Hit https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                  
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Hit https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal InRelease                     
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Fetched 228 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-525

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements
No candidate ver:  apg
No candidate ver:  libmecab2
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.11.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.11.0-7633-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.13.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.13.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.15.11-76051511-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.15.15-76051515-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.15.5-76051505-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.11.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.11.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.11.0-7633-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.13.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.13.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.15.11-76051511-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.15.15-76051515-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.15.5-76051505-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7633-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-7614-generic
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-7620-generic
No candidate ver:  rygel

Updating repository information
Hit https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable InRelease      
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal InRelease                     
Get:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease [4,428 B]
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48.9 kB]     
Hit https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Hit https://d3nt0h4h6pmmc4.cloudfront.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease [18.1 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease             
Hit https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy InRelease [24.4 kB]
Get:5 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy/contrib amd64 Packages [1,471 B]
Hit https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Get:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy/stable amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease      
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease [24.4 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1,100 B]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [160 B]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [7,500 B]
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [3,884 B]
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [3,060 B]
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [1,704 B]
Fetched 152 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information 

After updating your package information, the essential package 
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have 
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of 
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list 
for the current list of configured software sources. 
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade 
again later. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Here is my OS information:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: @user535733 System76 oryx pro.

Comment: @user535733 I put full update output :)

Comment: Your output shows that your sources seem an unmaintained mess. You have PPAs, wrong-version third-party repos, and other red-flags. Your sources also say "jammy' instead of 'focal' now. Advice: Back up your data and clean-install Ubuntu 22.04, and keep a much shorter leash on non-Ubuntu sources next time.

Comment: Thank you @user535733! I really appreciate it. I will do that :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a bug.

You could try a workaround by constantly changing the owner to root in another terminal:

```
while true;do chown -R root:root /run/user/1000; done
```

If you are finished change the directory back to be owners by your user